# Read image stored in Sqlflite database from Flutter

Tags: android, sql, flutter, sqlite, dart

The print statements while inserting the image in database are showing positive results.
Even while reading from the database, in the print statement's output I can see the Image data.
But I am unable to display it. How do verify where the problem lies?

**-------------------------- File: sqlfhelper.dart -----------------------------**

Table contains single item BLOB.

```
class SQLHelper {
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async 
  {
    await database
        .execute("CREATE TABLE items1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, picture BLOB )");
  }
```

Code for creating table:

```
static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase(
      'kindacode1.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
        await createTables(database);
      },
    );
  }
```

Here I pass the Image File to this function, convert it into `Uint8List` and then store in the table:

```
static Future<int> createItem(File? obj) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();

    Uint8List? pic;
    if (obj != null) {
      pic = await obj.readAsBytes();

      if (pic.isNotEmpty) {
        print("VVVV");
      }

    final data = {'picture': pic};
    final id = await db.insert('items1', data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return id;
  }
```

For reading from the database:

```
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('items1', orderBy: "id");
  }
```

**---------------------------- File: main.dart -------------------------------**

Stateful widget's initState: `_refreshJournals()` function reads from the database.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _refreshJournals(); 
  }
```

Idea is to read from the database and pull out the required image. This is the data that is getting printed by the print statement in the form of numbers.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _journals = [];

  void _refreshJournals() async {
    final data = await SQLHelper.getItems();
    setState(() {
      _journals = data;
  
      if (_journals.isNotEmpty) {
        print("WfW\n");
        print(data);

        _showForm(_journals[15]['id']);
      } 
    });
  }
```

Convert the image from uInt8List to Image using `fromRawPath`. I can see the print statements getting fulfilled here.

```
  void _showForm(int? id) async {
    if (id != null) {
      final existingJournal =
          _journals.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == 15);

      if (existingJournal.isNotEmpty) {
        print(existingJournal);
        myImage = File.fromRawPath(existingJournal['picture']);   
      } 
    }
  }
```

Being used as this:

```
 Image.file(
        myImage,
        scale: 0.5,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
 ),
```

It results into this in the GUI:
The strange shape with strange text is the place where the image should be.

Image is captured by camera of the phone and then stored in database to be read and displayed here :

[image]

Comment: Why do you store images in a database anyway? Why not to store as files and just insert paths into db?

Comment: @intraector I am new to all this. I request you to write an answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory for rendering from bytes.

```
 child: Image.memory(Uint8List bytes);
```

Or use MemoryImage class:

```
var _image = MemoryImage(image);
```

more [info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html):

Comment: A common way to store images is to save them as files and store their paths in database. This way you don't have to deal with bytes data and the performance is going to be better.

Comment: I'm glad you recommend best practices but that does not answer the question asked by the user. I'm just trying to help him solve the problem he has. Maybe he has a reason not to save the images because he wants to be sure of keeping all data saved.

Comment: sorry, I actually was writing an answer requested by the user in the comment section but mistakenly commented on your answer